# how to limit digits in an integer field in crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm working on CRM dynamics 2016 and I would like to know if there is a way in the field attributes (on creation) to limit the number of digits, for example: I need only four digit in my field, the user will insert a year value ( 1987 / 2017 /1955).
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

Set minimum value: 1000.

Set maximum value: 9999.